# Google play developer API - List all apps from my account

Tags: google-play, google-play-developer-api

Following this guide https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/ i am trying to find out if there is a way to list all games from my google play console but i can't find any. Is there a method to list all apps and package names from my account?

Thanks

Comment: hi @keepwalking, any update? Did you find solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51984202

As a summary, there are no methods exist in official api. Instead you can use Google Play search functionality.

Alternatively you can also use https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper project.

For a cloud based solution there is a commercial api https://serpapi.com/google-play-api which has 100 query/month.