# Google play API for pulling reviews and find list of applications

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

We're building a tool the lets users oAuth into their google play account so they can monitor the reviews of their app(s).

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews

Problem is we're not finding any specific API which provides list of published applications once the user has oAuthed into their account.

We need a list of their apps so we can grab the `packageName` per https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews/list

Comment: did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `android-publisher` API doesn't provide such functionality.

As a workaround, you may query Google Play web interface using `http://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:publisher-name` URL (where publisher-name is a parameter) and then parse the page to get the package names.
For example, to get all Google's apps, use the following query: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:Google+LLC.

Another option is to use one of the unofficial Google Play APIs, for example [this one](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-api) (first search result from Google).